# Jenkins "sh" messes up gradle command

Tags: linux, jenkins, gradle, devops

In short, I want to run this test in Jenkins CI

```
 sh ./gradlew run -PappArgs="['test@@password@@jdbc:postgresql://database.synchr.net:5432/matrixmaster_core','./viewregression.html']"
```

Goal is to export in the end viewregression.html and check the results of the test.

It works perfectly `./gradlew run -PappArgs="['test@@password@@jdbc:postgresql://database.company.net:5432/matrixmaster_core','./viewregression.html']"`
but when I add 
sh in the begining and close it with quotes Jenkins says:

```
Script1.groovy: 1: unexpected token: @ @ line 1, column 8.
```

Here is my whole jenkins-ci step:

```
   stage('View Regression Test') {
            steps {
                script {
                      sh "./gradlew run -PappArgs="['acc@@pass@@jdbc:postgresql://database.company.net:5432/matrixmaster_core','./viewregression.html']""

               }
            }
       }            
   } 
}
```

Comment: Have you tried escaping the inner quote with `\"`, i.e. `sh "./gradlew run -PappArgs=\"['acc@@pass@@jdbc:postgresql://database.company.net:5432/matrixmaster_core','./viewregression.html']\""`

Comment: I don't understand how I could not figure dthat out. So simple yet, true, thanks so much.

Comment: Do u happen to know what is the right way in the Jenkins ci to export the result from the test. Eventually to send an e-mail?

Comment: There's no "right" way. Usually test results could be published as result, some test plugins provide own reporting or publishing functionality. In your case it seems that you get a html file as result, so the easiest would probably to publish this html file with the "HTMLPublisher" plugin.